# Change text color of Dialog's title

Tags: android, android-dialog

This seems to be a very simple problem but I have searched and I can't find any solution.
I have a Dialog with content, like this one:

[image]

And I want to change the color of "Enter Password", the Dialog's title. How can I do it?

Comment: You can create your own activity, within it you an customize the layout however you want

Comment: But the title belongs to the dialog, not to the layout that I set on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `setCustomTitle(View customTitleView)` allows you to do that. You need to create a layout to set in this, and in that layout simply set to the TextView the style you want.

This method belongs to [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View customTitleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_title_view, null);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
.setCustomTitle(customTitleView);
```

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be a very simple answer:

```
String chars = getResources().getString(R.string.playerDialogTitle);
    SpannableString str = new SpannableString(chars);
    str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, chars.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PlayerActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle(str)
```